# grouping is giving wrong data if order_by is added

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model Lead. It has column `deal_value`. I want to get the count of leads for the given buckets for `deal_value`.
Buckets are

- from 0 to 1000 --> '<=1000'
- from 1001 to 100000 --> '<=100000'

So I annotate the queryset with 'bucket' and group by bucket and perform aggregation on it.

below is the code:

```
import django
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'design_studio_app.settings')
django.setup()



from dashboard.utils import get_accessible_objects_for_a_user
from accounts.models import User
from dashboard.qfilters import get_q_created_at

from django.db.models import  Case,  When, CharField, Value
from django.db.models import Count

user = User.objects.get(pk=1529)

# get the queryset
queryset = get_accessible_objects_for_a_user(
    'Leads', user)

# get the leads which are created this month
queryset = queryset.filter(get_q_created_at('this_month'))

queryset = queryset.order_by('deal_value')

measure_group_metric = 'deal_value'


min_value = 0
max_value = 100000
queryset = queryset.filter(
    **{measure_group_metric+"__gte": min_value, measure_group_metric+"__lte": max_value})


case_conditions = [
    When(**{measure_group_metric+"__gte":
            0, measure_group_metric+"__lte": 1000}, then=Value('<=1000')),
    When(**{measure_group_metric+"__gte":
            1001, measure_group_metric+"__lte": 100000}, then=Value('<=100000'))

]


queryset = queryset.annotate(
    bucket=Case(
        *case_conditions,
        default=None,
        output_field=CharField(),
    )

)

annotated_data = queryset.values('bucket').annotate(count=Count('id',allow_distinct=True))

print(annotated_data)
```

The annotated_data is

```
<SoftDeleteQuerySet [{'bucket': '<=1000', 'count': 26}, {'bucket': None, 'count': 1}, {'bucket': 
'<=100000', 'count': 8}, {'bucket': '<=100000', 'count': 1}, {'bucket': '<=100000', 'count': 1}]>
```

So the count is wrong. we can see that bucket **bucket': '<=100000'** is repeated.

However if I remove `order_by('deal_value')`. I get the correct output.

Why `order_by()` is affecting the output??. I need to have `order_by()`